# Read VarBinary(Max) using Pentaho ETL Tool

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

while trying to extract data from sql server where data stored in VarBinary(max) and store it into text file using pentaho ETL Tool. While extracting data getting invalid data which is stored as varbinary. Please let me know how we can extract varbinary data as it using pentaho etl.

[Output in Pentaho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajz3b.png)

[Input in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IRpx.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

In Table Output step of Pentaho, you can cast or convert your data to String using the native SQL query support of SQL Server when selecting the input rows. Use cast function to convert `varbinary(max)` to `nvarchar(max)`, as below

```
cast(column as nvarchar(max))
```

or

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(max), column, 0)
```